# [GUI] [Err] [SystemPaths.cc:425] Unable to find file with URI [model://model_pkg/models/base.dae]

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Im trying to load an sdf of a model in a project structure like this:

```
src/
  model_pkg/
    urdf/
      diff_bot.sdf
      diff_bot.xml
    models/
      base.dae
```

with this this sdf:

```
<sdf version='1.10'>
  <model name='diff_bot'>
    <link name='base_link'>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.010288200184753521</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>9.2e-05</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>4.8999999999999998e-05</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.000111</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <visual name='base_link_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>model://model_pkg/models/base.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=<insert path to project here>/src/model_pkg/models:
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=<insert path to project here>/src/model_pkg/models:

gz sim <insert path to project here>/src/model_pkg/urdf/diff_bot.sdf
```

However, when  I try to load the model with the .bash script, I get the error in the title, and other errors all relating to not being able to find the model, `base.dae`. Every post ive found thus far has said editing gazebo paths to lead to the model's location would fix the error(s), but editing the bash script to export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH and GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH hasn't fixed that for me.

Is there something I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28805/%5Bgui%5D-%5Berr%5D-%5Bsystempaths.cc:425%5D-unable-to-find-file-with-uri-%5Bmodel://model_pkg/models/base.dae%5D/) by [ryn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134869/ryn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` variable is used for Gazebo-classic. For Gazebo Garden, you need to set `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH`. It also needs to be the path of a directory such that starting from that directory, `model_pkg/models/base.dae` is valid. You can think of `model://` as being replaced by one of the directories in `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH`. See https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/resources.html for more details.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134869/ryn/) on 2023-02-24**:
editing my bash script to be:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall ruby

export GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH=/home/rydb/Projects/ROS2_easy/src:

gz sim /home/rydb/Projects/ROS2_easy/src/model_pkg/urdf/diff_bot.sdf
```

allowed the model to load. Also, the help command for gazebo simulation, for garden, `gz sim -h` lists env variables at the bottom. `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH` might no longer work one day so look for the equivalent env variable if y'all get stuck via your gazebo's help command